# How to transform a NOT IN into a LEFT JOIN (or a NOT EXISTS)

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following query that is quite complex and even though I tried to understand how to do using various sources online, all the examples uses simple queries where mine is more complex, and for that, I don't find the solution.

Here's my current query :

```
SELECT id, category_id, name 
    FROM orders AS u1 
WHERE added < (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND) 
    AND (executed IS NULL OR executed < (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
    AND category_id NOT IN (SELECT category_id 
                                FROM orders AS u2 
                            WHERE executed > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) 
                            GROUP BY category_id) 
GROUP BY category_id 
ORDER BY added ASC 
LIMIT 10;
```

The table orders is like this:

```
id
category_id
name
added
executed
```

The purpose of the query is to list n orders (here, 10) that belong in different categories (I have hundreds of categories), so 10 `category_id` different. The orders showed here must be older than a minute ago `(INTERVAL 60 SECOND)` and never executed `(IS NULL)` or executed more than a month ago.

The `NOT IN` query is to avoid treating a `category_id` that has already been treated less than 5 seconds ago. So in the result, I remove all the categories that have been treated less than 5 seconds ago.

I've tried to change the `NOT IN` in a `LEFT JOIN` clause or a `NOT EXISTS` but the switch results in a different set of entries so I believe it's not correct.

Here's what I have so far :

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.category_id, u1.name, u1.added 
    FROM orders AS u1 
    LEFT JOIN orders AS u2 
        ON u1.category_id = u2.category_id 
        AND u2.executed > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) 
WHERE u1.added < (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND) 
AND (u1.executed IS NULL OR u1.executed < (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND u2.category_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY u1.category_id 
LIMIT 10
```

Thank you for your help.

[Here's a sample data to try](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d663). In that case, there is no "older than 5 seconds" since it's near impossible to get a correct value, but it gives you some data to help out :)

Comment: It would be sooo much easier to answer your question if you included some sample data, the expected results based on the sample data, and the output produced by your query on the sample data.

Comment: Looking at your second query I think that you may need to change the greater than operator to a less than operator < like `AND u2.executed < (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) ` but without sample data I am unsure

Comment: Is this `LEFT JOIN urls as u2` a typo? In your first query the inner query is not selecting from `urls` but from `orders`.

Comment: Yes, my bad, the "urls" was a typo. I've fixed it. Regarding the sample data, I've put a SQLfiddle on it. I personally don't like using it because it's really slow and I never succeed in getting an output from them :/

Comment: While not of great help in this case (DDL and DML in the same tab make this specific query undebuggable), I've always found [rextester](http://www.rextester.com) fast and reliable... you may want to have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is using a column which doesn't exist in the table as a join condition.

```
ON u1.domain = u2.category_id
```

There is no column in your example data called "domain"

Your query is also using the incorrect operator for your 2nd join condition.

```
AND u2.executed > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
```

should be

```
AND u2.executed < (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
```

as is used in your first query

Comment: domain is a mistake on my end (an old column). But the order of the second condition was, on my mind, to get a list of the domains I don't wanted, that's why I place the `>` in that way.

Comment: So I've run some tests and regarding the way for `>` vs `<`, I (believe) I was correct: I want u2 to contain a list of items I don't want, to remove them from u1. So I want the u2.executed to be higher than 5 seconds ago. If you still think I'm wrong, please explain, I may have missed something ;)

Comment: The timestamp of something that happened longer than 5 seconds ago is going to be **less than** the current timestamp minus 5 seconds. For this reason you should use the less than operator. If you use the greater than operator, you are only going to retrieve records which have a timestamp greater than current timestamp minus 5 seconds, which will only get you result which happened between now and the last 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what I want, getting the records that happened between now and the last 5 seconds, in u2, in order to exclude that from the results from u1. I've tested on my local database by changing 5 seconds to one day (to have a simpler set) and played with the executed values. When settings `<`, I had invalid results, but when settings to `>`, the results appeared to be correct.

Comment: My mistake you are correct, I will update my answer accordingly. In return can you update your question to include the output you get from both queries and the difference between them. I can then shed light on your issue